# Expo, java.net.SocketTimeoutException:failed to connect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

am new to React native Expo I need to add some new modules on my project.  "expo": "33.0.0",   "react": "16.8.3", whenever I try to run my project am getting Error am not able to run the project. I tried all way to run the project like `set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME='192.168.0.102'`, firewall off, allowed inbound 19000 port etc. but am getting error.

when I enter `expo start -c`

```
 Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
Your JavaScript transform cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute).
Your native app is running at exp9c305c55e38f4d0e856f59397620314e://192.168.0.101:19000
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

then my laptop and mobile is connected with same network and same IP but am getting error and i don't know the port  19000 is different from my wifi

```
Uncaught Error:java.net.SocketTimeoutException:failed to connect to/192.168.1.20(port 19000)from/192.168.0.102(port 49615) after 10000ms
```

Please give some solution for it.

Answer (score 8):

It's failing because port `19000` is not open in your firewall. If you use linux OS open this port by running:

```bash
sudo ufw allow 19000/tcp
```

Comment: NO, actually its open in firewall but  mostly it will connect with port 80,19001. I don't no why?. AM using Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq6JT.png)First Check are you in tunnel connection?
If you are in tunnel connection then

First : ipconfig

then : set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.103 (IPv4 Address)

then:npm start

It worked for me. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: Yeah, its worked in mac but in windows not working

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by changing the network profile on the connected wifi from **private** to **public**.

[Expo Error Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZepv.jpg)

Comment: I'm using public wi-fi but have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if you still getting this problem but clearing the expo app solved form me just run `expo r -c`

Answer (score 1):

If the other options listed here don't work for you on Windows 10, updating the Windows firewall settings for allowing Expo Go to communicate with the development server should work:

1. Press the Windows key, type "Windows Defender Firewall," and click on "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security."
2. In the left pane, click on "Inbound Rules."
3. Click "New Rule..." in the right pane.
4. Select "Port" and click "Next."
5. Select "TCP" and enter "19000-19002" in the "Specific local ports" field. Click "Next."
6. Choose "Allow the connection" and click "Next."
7. Ensure that all three network types (Domain, Private, and Public) are checked, and click "Next."
8. Enter a name for the rule (e.g., "Expo Go Ports") and click "Finish."

Repeat steps 2 to 8 for "Outbound Rules" to create a new rule for outgoing connections.

After updating your firewall settings, restart Expo CLI and try connecting your mobile devices again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an issue with **Windows 10 Firewall**. I did these steps:

1. Windows Security -> Firewall & Network Protection - **Restore
   firewalls to Default**;
2. Opened up Windows Power Shell and CD into
   my Expo app folder;
3. Ran: npm run start (in this step Windows Firewall will ask you if you **allow** this app in the firewall)
4. Choose to allow and include **Private and Public Networks**.

Done!